# iMessage with iCloud mail aliases?

Tags: ios, icloud, messages, alias

Is it possible to use an iCloud email alias as the Caller ID for iMessage?

When I try to enter an alias on "Receive At > Add Another Email..." I always get an error popup titled "iMessage Activation" - "An error occurred while verifying your email". 
I've also tried to go to appleid.apple.com and enter one alias. When I press save, the page shows some loading activity but stays the same and never saves the alias. I've tested it both on Safari and Firefox. With other email addresses it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In trying what I think you are wanting to do.
I had to enter my real email address and password to activate the service.

(Remember your real apple ID *youname@mac.com*/*yourname@me.com* is your user name and an alias email address is NOT)

Once I did this. My apple id is used for the first email address.
I can then add another email address below it.

the second one was one of my alias emails to my apple email.

Logging out of this service will remove both addresses.

Comment: I had already activated the service, with my real apple ID and then added it as my first email address. Whenever I try to add an alias on iOS, I get the error described above. If I do it on appleid.apple.com, then nothing happens and it doesn't allow me to add iCloud email aliases. With other email addresses it works.

Comment: Are you using for example: a '@mac.com' for the ID login, and a '@me.com' for the alias. Which would not work AFAIK

Comment: No. Both are @me.com